# What does the story mean that Amy told on the girls' night out in "The Big Bang Theory"?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-big-bang-theory

In season four of *The Big Bang Theory*, "The 21 Second Excitation", Bernadette dared Amy to tell a dirty story. The story Amy told was not in English (gibberish, I believe). However, I'm curious if what Amy said had some meaning. Does anybody know what that means?

Comment: In the episode she actually says it’s The Miller’s Tale by Chaucer.

Answer (score 3):

The quote from the episode is as follows.

> **Amy:** *And Absolon hath kist hir nether ye, and Nicholas is scalded in the towte. This tale is doon, and God save al the rowte.”*
>
> **Penny:** *What the hell was that?*
>
> **Amy:** *Bernadette dared me to tell a dirty story. The Miller’s Tale by Chaucer is the dirtiest story I know. It would have been hidden in
> sock drawers if people in the 14th century had worn socks.*

[*The Miller's Tale*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Miller%27s_Tale) is written in [*Middle English*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_English), which is why you've mistaken it for gibberish.

---

The passage she's quoting is a summary of the events of the tale. The carpenter's wife has been slept with (despite the carpenter's jealous watchful eye), Absolon kissed Alisoun's anus and Nicholas was scalded with a poker after farting in Absolon's face.

> *Thus swyved was this carpenteris wyf,*
> **Thus screwed was this carpenter's wife,**
> *For al his kepyng and his jalousye,*
> **In spite of all his guarding and his jealousy,**
> *And Absolon hath kist hir nether ye,*
> **And Absolon has kissed her lower eye,**
> *And Nicholas is scalded in the towte.*
> **And Nicholas is scalded in the rump.**
> *This tale is doon, and God save al the rowte!*
> **This tale is done, and God save all this company!**
>
> <sub><sup>[Harvard Press](https://chaucer.fas.harvard.edu/pages/millers-prologue-and-tale)</sup></sub>